# How to select a from two tables by composite primary key?

Tags: php, html, database

I am trying to select **item_id** that exists in items table as a primary key, and exists in offers table with the name **offer_id** as a composite key with other fields, and what i want is to get the information of the items that exists in the offers table (the items that has offer).

I tried this way but there's no results showed up:

```
<section class="main-content">          
  <ul class="thumbnails listing-products">

<?php
try {
  if (isset($_POST["pro"])) {
    $cat = $_POST["pro"];
    require ("connection.php");
    $sql2 = " SELECT * FROM items,offers WHERE item_id=offer_id  ";
    $rs2 = $db->query($sql2);
    foreach ($rs2 as $r2) {
?>                                          
    <li class="span3">
      <div class="product-box">
        <span class="sale_tag"></span>
        <p><a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r2['item_id']; ?>" ><img src="images/<?php echo $r2['item_photo']; ?>" alt="" /></a></p>
        <a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r2['item_id']; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $r2['item_name']; ?></a><br/>
        <a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r2['item_id']; ?>"><?php echo $r2['item_brand']; ?></a>
        <p class="price"><?php echo $r2['item_price']; ?>BHD</p>
      </div>
    </li>
<?php
   } ?>
                                                       
<?php
  $db = NULL;
  }
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
?>                              
  </ul>
</section>
```

Also this is the items table structure:
[image: item table]

And this is the offer table structure:
[image: offer table]

Comment: This looks abit sus item_id=offer_id. Your looking for he string offer_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna do something like this, you need to JOIN tables on a point like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN offers ON items.item_id=offers.offer_id WHERE ....
```

and later after WHERE do something like **items.item_name LIKE "%xyz%"** - depends how you wanna specify this, or just leave without WHERE and gets all data from items and later added offers, if they exists.

Comment: use that SELECT as yours $sql2